# eevee - get opengl to wait for all samples?

Tags: rendering, opengl, eevee-render-engine

Version 2.80.4 - I have a spot lamp with volumetric lighting enabled and I've adjusted the samples and volumetric tile size to get a decent enough cone of light once the viewport finishes loading. Here's what it looks like in the viewport:[image]

However, once I render either an opengl image or animation, it doesn't wait for all samples to load before finishing/moving on to the next frame and I get this result:
[image]

It seems to only apply a fraction of the samples to the spot lamp's volumetric light cone before finishing.

Am I missing something or is this life in pre-release 2.8?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about experimental development software

Comment: I agree, there's no guarantee that any solution will still aplly in the future.

Comment: We all have questions about Eevee, but as it's still unfinished we just have to be patient.